# Find x such that $495x \equiv 90 \pmod{6}$ or explain why it does not exist

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

The questions are:

i) Find $\gcd(315, 495)$

ii) Find $x$ such that $495x \equiv 90 \pmod{6}$ or explain why it does not exist

I did (i) and got $\gcd(315, 495)=45$. How do I find the answer for (ii)? How is it related to (i)?

Here's my attempt for (ii): (I did not use the equation in (i))

$495x \equiv 90 \mod{6}$

whereby $495 \equiv 3 \pmod{6}$

$$3x \equiv 90 \pmod{6}$$
$$3x \equiv 0 \pmod{6}$$

Hence, the smallest integer of $x$ is $2$?

I would like to know if there's a solution that uses the equation in (i)

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the question right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common thread between these two questions is that they both involve breaking integers down into their unique prime factor decomposition (using the [Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)).  This allows you to find common factors in the relevant expressions and simplify to obtain solutions.

---

(i) When you want to find the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of two numbers, the simplest thing to do is to break those numbers down into their unique prime factor decomposition:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
315 &= 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7, \\[6pt]
495 &= 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 11. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

The greatest common divisor of these two numbers will consist of the shared prime factors, so it is:

$$\text{gcd}(315, 495) = 3^2 \times 5 = 45.$$

---

(ii) For the latter problem, you are trying to find integers $x$ and $k$ for which:

$$495 \cdot x = 6 \cdot k + 90.$$

Again, we can break the relevant numbers down into their unique prime factor decomposition:

$$3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 11 \cdot x = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot k + 2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5.$$

Eliminating the common factor and grouping terms gives:

$$3 \cdot 5 \cdot 11 \cdot x = 2 \cdot (k + 3 \cdot 5).$$

So a solution is obtained by taking $k=3 \cdot 5 \cdot 10 = 150$ and $x=2$.  That is:

$$990 \equiv 90 \quad \text{(mod } 6 \text{)}.$$

Comment: thank you! i get it now

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if the question is expecting you to use the fact:

If $\gcd(a,b) = d$ and $a|bm$ then $a|dm$ (as none of the factors other than $d$ will have any factors in common with $a$).

so $495x \equiv 90 \pmod 6$ means

$6|495x - 90 = 45(11x - 2)$ and as $\gcd(6, 45)=3$

$6|3(11x-2)$ so $2|11x - 2$ and so $2|11x$ and so $2|x$.

For any even $x$ we have $495x \equiv 90 \pmod 6$.

.... which seems a pretty convoluted way to do it.

===

Far more straightforward would be

$495x \equiv 90 \pmod 6$

$3x \equiv 0 \pmod 6$

$6|3x$ so $2|x$